# how to use Java 8 option -XX:+UsePerfData

Tags: java, performance

The java 8 oracle documentation mention the option -XX:+UsePerfData (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html) with the following description:

```
-XX:+UsePerfData
    Enables the perfdata feature. This option is enabled by default to allow JVM monitoring and performance testing. Disabling it suppresses the creation of the hsperfdata_userid directories. To disable the perfdata feature, specify -XX:-UsePerfData.
```

But I don't how to use theses perfdata.
Though which software / tool can I analyse theses data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-XX:+UsePerfData` is responsible for collecting [HotSpot Performance Counters](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bjvmstat) and exporting them to external tools. This option is ON by default.

With PerfData enabled, HotSpot JVM creates a file under `/tmp/hsperfdata_<user>` directory for each JVM process. Many tools, including `jps`, `JConsole` and `VisualVM`, scan this directory to find running JVMs. If you disable PerfData, the JVM will not be discovered by these tools automatically.

`jstat` is one of the standard JDK tools relying on HotSpot Performance Counters. `jstat` will not work with JVMs that have PerfData disabled.

`jcmd <pid> PerfCounter.print` is another standard command that prints all Performance Counters exported by the given process.